# JPA criteria select multiple fields from subquery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the following SQL query that I'm trying to write using Criteria JPA.

```
select op3.* from operator op3 where (op3.mp, op3.date_to, op3.date_from) in 
(select op.mp, op.date_to, op.date_from from operator op
group by op.mp, op.date_to, op.date_from
having count(*) > 1 or min(gross_price) < 0);
```

I've written the code, but i am not able to select multiple fields from subquery. Right now i select only the mp, but i need to select also the date_from and date_to and to add them in the "in" condition from criteriaBuilder.

```
fun method(): Specification<Operator> {

            return Specification { root, query, cb ->

                val subquery =
                    query.subquery(Long::class.java)
                val groupBySubQueryRoot =
                    subquery
                        .from(Operator::class.java)

                subquery.select(
                    groupBySubQueryRoot.get(
                        Operator_.mp
                    )
                )
                    .groupBy(
                        groupBySubQueryRoot.get(Operator_.mp),
                        groupBySubQueryRoot.get(Operator_.dateFrom),
                        groupBySubQueryRoot.get(Operator_.dateTo)
                    )
                    .having(
                        cb.or(
                            cb.gt(cb.count(groupBySubQueryRoot), 1),
                            cb.lt(cb.min(groupBySubQueryRoot.get(Operator_.grossPrice)), 0)
                        )
                    )

                cb.`in`(root.get(Operator_.mp)).value(subquery)
            }
        }
```